# Combining two or more 3gp and mp4 files into a single file

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project, there is a scenario to combine two or more 3gp or mp4 files into a single file.
I succeeded to combine avi and wmv files using [Splicer](http://splicer.codeplex.com) from CodePlex

But my requirement is to combine 3gp and mp4 files.
I am using asp.net (c#).

I will be thankful if anyone provide me guidelines to achieve this using c#.

Thanks in advance,
Sujith.S

Comment: What have you done so far? This is not a "Do my homework" platform. See [faq]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know it is not a "Do my homework" platform. What i have done is described in the post itself. I am not aware of concatenation of 3gp and mp4 files. I want a solution for that.